# Problems when pasting Outlook 2010 signature logo into message body

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, image-editing, photoshop-cs6, email-signature

Whenever I paste my company logo into a message in Outlook 2010, I run into a variety of complications and anomalies.

The dimensions of my original logo image are 315x174 (source image is a PNG file).

I am scaling this image down in Photoshop CS6 to a variety of smaller sizes for testing my Outlook signature (300x166, 250x138, 200x110,150x83 and 100x55 pixels).

300x166 = no distortion. This looks the same as in Photoshop (but far too large to use in my signature).

250x130  = distorted (gets stretched much wider by Outlook when pasting into message body).

200x110 = looks reasonable, but seems to have been scaled to a different size (smaller) by Outlook for no obvious reason.

150x83  = for some reason, this is scaled by Outlook to the exact same size that 200x110 was scaled to. In fact, a large range of similar dimensions are scaled to the exact same image size by Outlook. This is very frustrating. Why is this happening and what can be done to prevent it?

100x55  = when pasting my logo from Photoshop to Outlook with these dimensions all that happens is the cursor jumps forwards about an inch on the screen, leaving a blank space where the image was supposed to go.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try opening the PNG in Paint and do a Ctrl+A in Paint and Ctrl+V in Outlook.

Comment: That would probably work too. Turns out I didn't need to even resave as a PNG, I could just copy and paste from Photoshop to Paint, then copy and paste from Paint to Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually discovered that copying and pasting *directly from Photoshop* to Outlook was causing the problem. There must be some extra data that goes onto the clipboard that Outlook can't interpret properly.

Here is my new workflow that solves all problems mentioned in my question:

1) Adjust image size in Photoshop to exact size required (control + alt + i, then set desired width and height)

2) Copy image from Photoshop to clipboard

3) Paste from clipboard into Paint

4) Copy from Paint back onto clipboard (there is now an Outlook-friendly version of the image in the clipboard)

5) Paste from clipboard into Outlook

Doing this gives the best of both worlds: Photoshop does a better job of resizing images (no jagged edges), and going via Paint ensures there are no glitches (unexpected resizing/squishing of images).

Hopefully this helps other people having trouble getting their logo to look the way they want in Outlook!

Comment: So like my workflow, copying text from word into notepad than into desired application ;)